# If Else statement javascript with var

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I have this code so far, however I cannot get the `if/else` to work.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickHandler(evt) {
    var agevar = confirm('Text for confirm!');
if ( agevar == true ) {
    window.location('http://websiteone.com'); }
else {
    window.location('http://websitetwo.com');} }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<li><a onclick="return clickHandler()">Hit</a>
```

When I click the 'Hit' button it works just fine and the confirm box shows up, however, whatever you click on the box it does not redirect.

Comment: Try `window.location = "..."`

Comment: Consider to use debugger (F12 in most browsers) and put breakpoint in the function - than step throuhg and see what is happeneing.

Comment: ... or just observe the giveaway error message in the console: `TypeError: Property 'location' of object [object Window] is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 window.location = 'http://websitetwo.com';
```

Further reading see documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: This worked... lol. Can't believe it was such a stupid error... thanks.

Comment: Glad i could help! Please tick my answer if it helped for others to find!